# App Store app listing showing only development language as supported

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store

I have 3 localizations supported in my app - English, Hebrew and Arabic, where English is selected as the development language.

[image: Xcode Localiztions]

However, the app's listing page in the App Store shows only English as a supported language:

[image]

What could possibly be the reason for this? Am I missing any setting for the localizations to be shown in the listing page?